# WPF: Make AvalonEdit Unfocusable and Uneditable

Tags: c#, wpf, avalonedit

How can I make AvalonEdit unfocusable and uneditable in my WPF App?

I've tried this:

```
<avalonEdit:TextEditor
    x:Name="AvalonQuery"
    xmlns:avalonEdit="http://icsharpcode.net/sharpdevelop/avalonedit"
    FontFamily="Consolas"
    SyntaxHighlighting="SQL"
    ShowLineNumbers="True"
    IsReadOnly="True"
    Focusable="False"/>
```

`IsReadOnly="True"` works, but I don't know why `Focusable="False"` simply doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<avalonEdit:TextEditor.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type avalonEdit:TextArea}">
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
    </Style>
</avalonEdit:TextEditor.Resources>
```

You can see here: https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvalonEdit/blob/master/ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit/TextEditor.xaml